# How can I get better performance on union clause on t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I have three tables. Each table contains more than 3M rows. I run following code:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, [date], 1 as type FROM table_1
    UNION
    SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, [date], 2 as type FROM table_2 
    UNION
    SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, [date], 3 as type FROM table_3
) AS tb 
tb.[date] BETWEEN (start_date) AND (end_date)  
ORDER BY [date] DESC OFFSET n ROWS FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY
```

But when i get large date interval the query run slower. For example: When i get 2019-01-01 and 2019-04-01 interval the query run about 13-14 seconds:

[image: Execution plan]

This result is very bad. I want to get result in 1 second. What can I do?

Comment: You can try to add the where condition in the individual queries.

Comment: For starters, as the result of your queries never overlap (but SQL Server can't know that), you can use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION` to save a sort step. Furthermore, the optimizer can't always effectively fold outer conditions to inside queries, so you may want to repeat the `WHERE date BETWEEN` clause in each of the queries.

Comment: This query also vitally needs indexing in all tables on the `date` column, otherwise huge and inefficient table scans are unavoidable. And last but certainly not least, `OFFSET .. FETCH NEXT` is an inherently inefficient construct that gets slower the larger the `OFFSET` gets, so make sure you aren't trying to make the database do things it just can't do fast.

Comment: i write individual where but i only give me 1 -2 seconds faster. and also i use union all clause. but it didn't help me too

Comment: Yes i create index on date column each table. after do it the execution time down to 13-14 second.

Comment: If the index isn't covering and the date range is large SQL Server might not use it (or if it does use it it may need to do lots of lookups. In this last case you may find it ends up doing lookups for rows ultimately discarded by the `OFFSET .. FETCH`. What are the table definitions (including indexes) and what does the execution plan look like?

Comment: the execution plan such as:

Comment: How many rows does the above query return? is it slow because the server has to send too many rows?

Comment: i add execution plan image.

Comment: I want only get 100 rows

Comment: To effectively share an execution plan, use [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), much nicer than an image.

Comment: So your index isn't being used anyway. Probably because it doesn't cover all the columns used in the select list.

Answer (score 7):

Start by using `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, [date], 1 as type FROM table_1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, [date], 2 as type FROM table_2 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, [date], 3 as type FROM table_3
     ) AS tb 
WHERE tb.[date] BETWEEN (start_date) AND (end_date)  
ORDER BY [date] DESC
OFFSET n ROWS FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY;
```

SQL incurs overhead for removing duplicates with `UNION`.  `UNION ALL` does not incur this overhead.

In addition, an index on `date` in each of the tables should help.  SQL Server has a good optimizer that usually pushes such conditions down to the individual queries in a `UNION`/`UNION ALL` subquery.

Comment: This answer assumes that it is acceptable or desirable to have the duplicates show up.  This may or may not be the case, depending upon the requirements of the project.  Also, of course, there are transmission overheads for more rows being returned.

Comment: @JosephDoggie: as there is no overlap in the subqueries (due to the different `type`s) the duplicates would only show up if they're already present in the base table, and then a `DISTINCT` on the subqueries would still sort them out more efficiently than `UNION`.

Comment: In this case it is still going to have to combine the three streams into sorted date order (likely with a merge join assuming index on `date`) so duplicate removal shouldn't be a massively expensive additional step anyway,

Comment: @JosephDoggie . . . There are no duplicates -- at least between tables -- because of the `type` column.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest creating a covering index on each table similar to:

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON table_1 (date) INCLUDE (column1, column2, column3)
```

This should help with the WHERE clause. Plus SQL Server won't have to touch the tables as all the required information is present in the index.

---

Here is another stab at this. Assuming that `OFFSET n ROWS FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY` matches a very small percentage of rows between start and end date, write a query such as this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    -- find the first date after n + m window
    SELECT date
    FROM (
        SELECT date FROM table_1 UNION ALL
        SELECT date FROM table_2 UNION ALL
        SELECT date FROM table_3
    ) AS x
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-04-01'
    ORDER BY date DESC OFFSET (n + m) ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT date, column_1, column_2, column_3, 1 AS type FROM table_1 UNION ALL
    SELECT date, column_1, column_2, column_3, 1 AS type FROM table_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT date, column_1, column_2, column_3, 1 AS type FROM table_3
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE date <= '2019-04-01' AND date > (SELECT date FROM cte1)
ORDER BY date DESC OFFSET n ROWS FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Or they could consider making date the leading column in a clustered index on all these tables as they are all heaps at the moment. Whether or not that would be a good idea isn't possible to know with current information

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that the query planner is smart enough to limit the results of the union by the where clause outside of the union, so try moving the date condition into each of the queries in the union, so that you aren't unioning the entirety of the three tables together before operating on the condition:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, [date], 1 as type FROM table_1 where table_1.[date] between (start_date) and (end_date)
    UNION
    SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, [date], 2 as type FROM table_2 where table_2.[date] between (start_date) and (end_date) 
    UNION
    SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, [date], 3 as type FROM table_3 where table_3.[date] between (start_date) and (end_date)
) AS tb 
ORDER BY [date] DESC OFFSET n ROWS FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: SQL 2012 seems to move the where clause automatically.